# Is there an efficient way to determine the index of a specific core data record

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to find the index of a core data record using the following code, where [self numItems] returns the number of records. The code takes about 0.2 seconds on average to execute. I am interested in speeding it up. Thanks in advance.

```
- (NSInteger) indexWithTaskID:(NSInteger)eventID
{
    for (NSInteger i=0;i<[self numItems];i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController
                                      objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger myEventID = [(NSNumber *)[managedObject valueForKey:@"eventID"] intValue];

        if (myEventID == eventID) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What's the context that you call this? If you had the full managedObject, you could call `[self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:managedObject]`.

Comment: I don't have the specific managedObject when this method is called. I only have the eventID. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still curious of the context.

Comment: I misspoke in my previous comment. I do have the specific managedObject but only for a specific predicate. If I change the predicate (to return a subset of records, for example), the index of that managedObject may change. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using a fetch request?

Comment: Note that I am not interested in the manageObject or its contents. I am only interested in finding the index of that managedObject with a different predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit backward of what this is setup for, I'd try to avoid needing to find this index if you have much data, but if you really need to know the index then you might be stuck doing this search. If the predicate is sorted, you could do quite a bit better then a linear search, maybe a [simple binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) could make enough improvement.